# ISO 4 abbreviation of "Journal of Computational Physics: X"

Tags: abbreviations

Is it "J. Comput. Phys. X" or "J. Comput. Phys.: X" (with the colon)? There is a *punctuation* section in the ISO 4 standard definition (see Section 4.6 [here](https://www.iso.org/obp/ui/#iso:std:iso:4:ed-3:v1:en)), but the document is paywalled and I don't have access to it.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it isn’t about language.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that https://www.slideshare.net/agelsorin/iso-00004-1997 is accurate, section 4.6 of ISO 4:1997 reads:

> The punctuation which occurs in the full title shall be retained in the abbreviated title with the exception of commas and full stops (periods); commas shall be omitted in the abbreviated title and full stops shall be replaced by commas. However, full stops may be retained in the abbreviated title when they are used with acronyms, initialisms, ordinal numbers or dependent title designations.
>
> Full stops shall only be used to indicate an abbreviation. Full stops may be omitted from abbreviated word in applications that require limited use of punctuation.

By this logic, the colon stays a colon and "Journal of Computational Physics: X" is abbreviated as "J. Comput. Phys.: X"